# search Hbase record using java API?

Tags: java, hbase, bigdata

I want to search record base on value and my application in Java

I am store record using below code

```
HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);
Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
put.add(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier),
        Bytes.toBytes(value));
table.put(put);
```

I pass  values

```
    Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("rowkey"));
    put.add(Bytes.toBytes("family1"), Bytes.toBytes("qualifier1"),
            Bytes.toBytes("this is test record"));
```

this is my get implementation

```
Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("rowkey"));
            String[] family = { "row1" };
get.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("family1"),Bytes.toBytes("qualifier1"));
Result rs = table.get(get);
```

now I want to search this record by "this is test record" value.

help me to found this record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using filter you can do search on any of the element and you can pass different combination
for  SubstringComparator BinaryComparator

```
FilterList flist = new FilterList();

flist.addFilter(new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("Predicatevalue"))));
flist.addFilter(new QualifierFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL,new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("Subject value"))));
flist.addFilter(new ValueFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL,new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("Objectvalue"))));
```

This work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `get()` method on `HTable` and the Get class, which are analogous to the `put()` method on `HTable` and the `Put` class.

Comment: Yes I know result get by search but how can search rows by values "this is test record".

Comment: You can use the filter.

Comment: can you give one example